# Genexus Traning Videos

Tags: genexus

I tried the step-by-step from Training videos, but this error prompts whenever I press F5.

```
Specifying Country ...
error spc0052: Attribute CityId must be present on the screen or assigned by a rule. (Transaction 'Country', Details)
error spc0104: Grids are mandatory for all levels but the first one. (Transaction 'Country', Details)
warning spc0043: CityId is not instantiated. (Transaction 'Country', Details)
Processing inferred calls...
Failed: Specification
Failed: Run Developer Menu
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you are having problems with transaction structure and its form (screen layout).

**About SPC0052 error**

Attribute CityId seems to be part of the transaction key. I assume you have a structure similar to:

```
CountryId*
CountryName
      (CityId*
       CityName)
```

Every key attribute (CountryId and CityId in this example) must be present on the screen or assigned in the transaction rule. Otherwise, how will it have a value? (remember that Key attributes cannot be “null”)

Further information: https://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/wiki?6432,Specification+Codes+from+spc0050+to+spc0099

**About SPC0104 error**

It seems that you defined a grid for the first level (countryId) and this is not allowed.
For the above sample structure, the form should be “plain” for the first level and “grid” for the second level

Further information: https://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/wiki?6433,Specification+Codes+from+spc0100+to+spc0149

How to fix them?
It depends on the structure and form that you have defined. Perhaps the easiest way is to apply default form (positioned at transaction form, option edit/Apply Default (Web Layout)

Comment: Hi Thanks for your response, what I only did was insert Level, but corresponding field didn't reflect when I clicked the "Web Layout" Tab.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason the attribute CityId is not being automatically added on the WebLayout of the Transaction "Country". If that is the case, you will see a red mark instead of a green mark in the WebLayout panel.

[image: Red Mark on Web Layout]

[image: Green Mark on Web Layout]

To correct this behavior go to Tools -> Refactoring -> Apply Defaults (Web Form) and select the respective transaction (Country).